# passing a variable to urlopen() and reading it again in python using bs4

Tags: python, html, variables, beautifulsoup, logic

I am planning to open a bunch of links where the only thing changing is the year at the end of the links. I am using the code below but it is returning a bunch of errors. My aim is to open that link and filter some things on the page but first I need to open all the pages so I have the test code. Code below:

```
from xlwt import *
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from xlwt.Style import *

j=2014
for j in range(2015):
    conv=str(j)
    content = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_%s").read() %conv
    j+=1

print(content)
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\urltest.py", line 11, in <module>
    content = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_%s").read() %conv
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

A little guidance required. If there is any other way to pass the variables[2014, 2015 etc] also it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may be because you are declaring `j` and then modifying it at the end of your loop. `range()` already does this for you so you don't have to increment it. Also, your string interpolation syntax looks wrong. Be sure to include the variable immediately after the string. `print("Hi %s!" % name)`.

Try:

```
for j in range(2015):
    conv=str(j)
    content = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_%s" % conv).read()
```

Also, I am assuming you don't want to query from years 0 to 2015. You can call `range(start_year, end_year)` to iterate from `[start_year, end_year)`.

Answer (score 1):

As cesar pointed out in his answer, incrementing j is not needed since you are already looping with it. Also, j=0 in the beginning doesn't have any effect because your loop starts from 0 anyway.

This will create a dictionary called contents where each key is referring to the page of the corresponding year:

```
import urllib2

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_%d"

contents = {year:urllib2.urlopen(url % year).read()
         for year in range(2014,2015+1)}
```

---

However, if you have multiple pages to load, I think the best way would be to save each file to your local disk first and then load from there for further processing.

This would be because you probably want to go back to your parsing process multiple times but want to download the files only once. So consider doing something like:

```
#reading, (only once)
for year in range(start_year,end_year+1):
    with open('year_%d.txt' % year,'w') as f:
        f.write(urllib2.urlopen(url % year).read())

#processing
for year in range(start_year,end_year+1):
    with open('year_%d.txt','r') as f:
        page = f.read()
    process(page)
```